# Squid ignores multi-WAN load balancing in pfSense

Tags: freebsd, squid, pfsense

If squid3 package is installed and configured as transparent proxy, then load-balancing gateway group is ignored. I.e. if some ISP is down, then some web pages can't be opened and not routed to another ISP.

How to fix? I wish both transparent proxy and gateway group.